# location in Ionic project for android

Tags: android, angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

In a simple Ionic app I have to get current location on map. It's works fine in browser when i click find me, but it's not working on actual Android device.

I'm using the following code

**View.html**

```
            <ion-view view-title="{{navTitle}}">
             <ion-content>
                    <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
            </ion-content>
             <ion-footer-bar class="bar-stable">
                <a ng-click="centerOnMe()" class="button button-icon icon ion-navigate">Find Me</a>
             </ion-footer-bar>
            </ion-view>
```

**controllers.js**

```
        .controller('googlemap', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {
               $scope.navTitle = 'Google Map';
              $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function(){
            if ( angular.isDefined( $scope.map ) ) {
                google.maps.event.trigger($scope.map, 'resize');
            }
          });

          function initialize() {
                //var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493,-89.381388);
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.520430300000000000,73.856743699999920000);
                var mapOptions = {
                  center: myLatlng,
                  zoom: 16,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                    mapOptions);

                //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
                var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!</a></div>";
                var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content: compiled[0]
                });

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: myLatlng,
                  map: map,
                  title: 'Pune(India)'
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                  infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });

                $scope.map = map;
              }
              initialize();

              $scope.centerOnMe = function() {
                if(!$scope.map) {
                  return;
                }

                $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
                  content: 'Getting current location...',
                  showBackdrop: false
                });

                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
                  $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
                  $scope.loading.hide();
                }, function(error) {
                  alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
                });
              };

              $scope.clickTest = function() {
                alert('Example of infowindow with ng-click')
              };

        })
```

Also in my device on the device Location but still I have problem.I got following output on my screen for long time.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Isn't it easier to just use the  `ngCordova $cordovaGeoLocationPlugin` ? You can get the position from this plugin ( latitude and longitude) and then pass this in GoogleAPI. I think it will be lot easier that way.

[ngCordova geoLocationPlugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/)

Just a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, for the solutions!

Comment: I used this plugin, it works well on the browser, but  it doesn't capture location from internal GPS in smart phone device. Why?

Answer (score 0):

This example works perfect in case you start the app with GPS on.  But starting with GPS off in you device, and after that, entering in the app and selecting GPS on,  the function returns always GPS timeout ERROR = 3.   Any solution for that?
I have posted this error here:
[When I start the App with GPS off , and later GPS is activated, Location is not detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277660/when-i-start-the-app-with-gps-off-and-later-gps-is-activated-location-is-not)