# When I start the App with GPS off , and later GPS is activated, Location is not detected

Tags: ionic-framework, gps, geolocation

I am having problems with GPS detection over Google Maps in Ionic App. When I start the App with GPS off and later I change from Settings device to GPS on, clicking by Find Me button - centerOnMe() function -  the GPS is not working. The function responses always

```
`Error: GPS Timeout! ERROR = 3`
```

At the beginning I thought that was a cache problem but I have found out that is not that. It doesn´t matter the using $state.reload from the view. ¿does anyone get the same issue? Thanks for the support. I attach the function below:

```
  $scope.centerOnMe = function() {

        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        console.log('Click on Find Me');

        if(!map) {
            return;
        }

        $ionicLoading.show({
            content: 'Getting current location...',
            showBackdrop: false
        });

        //$state.reload('app.map');
        watchPositionId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {                    
                navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchPositionId);
                var latitude     = position.coords.latitude;
                var longitude    = position.coords.longitude;
                $scope.latitude  = latitude;
                $scope.longitude = longitude;
                var geolocpoint  = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                map.setCenter(geolocpoint);     
        });
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                   var lat  = position.coords.latitude
                   var long = position.coords.longitude                
                   $scope.center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
                   $ionicLoading.hide();
                   console.log("GPS is enabled" + $scope.center);
         }, function(err) {
                  // error
                  if (err.code == 1)     { console.log('GPS disabled! ERROR = '       + err.code);  }
                  else if(err.code == 2) { console.log('GPS is unavailable! ERROR = ' + err.code);  }
                  else if(err.code == 3) { console.log('Error: GPS Timeout! ERROR = ' + err.code);  }   
                  $ionicLoading.hide();
         }, {
                  enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000
            }  
         );

       });      
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You better to use [this](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) plugin,

```
 cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic
```

It will directly check whether gps is enabled or not.

Fore more details check following ionic forum issues,

1. [Geo location timeout vs location permission error](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/geolocation-timeout-vs-location-permission-error/36635)
2. [Get Current Position not working after turning the GPS off on the device even if it turned on again?](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/getcurrentposition-not-working-after-turning-the-gps-off-on-the-device-even-if-it-turned-on-again/20291)

Hopes this will help you !!